# What good practices can we identify for creative writing posts?

Tags: discussion

One of our biggest challenges is figuring out how to match the strict SE Q&A format to the subjective, creative, and rather abstract field of creative writing.

We've seen a lot of great questions and a lot of great answers - **what helpful elements or practices can we learn from them**, that we might be able to apply to future posts as well? Can you look at a particular "really good" question/answer, and identify *why* it was so good?

Any observations and suggestions are welcome - both broad and narrow.

Comment: Related: [What poor/annoying practices can we identify for creative writing posts?](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/444/26).

Answer (score 5):

What I find tremendously useful in answers is **examples from popular culture.** Examples add so much substance to an answer - they turn it from general, abstract advice, into a useful reference I can study, understand, and reuse.

In this sense, I feel like such examples fulfill the "Back it up!" idea discussed in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). It does exactly what that article discusses - it turns an opinion into an experience that can be shared; it backs up opinion with references.

My personals standbys for this include books, comics, and movies, including *Ender's Game*, *Game of Thrones*, *The Matrix*, *Harry Potter*, *Dragonlance*... some others, no doubt, and no less geeky than these :P

Unfortunately, attempts to use lesser-known works [don't work nearly as well](https://writers.stackexchange.com/a/3361/1046) even if they serve as a good demonstration of your point.